# How to check the given property is not present or it's greater/less than some value in Gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, gremlin-server, tinkerpop

How to check the given property is not present or it's greater/less than some value in Gremlin?

```
g.V(1).hasNot('end_date_time').hasNext()

g.V(1).has('end_date_time', gte(current_timestamp)).hasNext()
```

Want to combine the above queries to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `or` the two conditions together

```java
g.V(1).or(hasNot('end_date_time'),
          has('end_date_time', gte(current_timestamp))
```